# How to implode and update this item to database

Tags: php, sql, implode

I have table item like this:

```
id_item       color           stock
1         red,green,yellow   10,20,30
```

here a table cart :

```
id id_trans     id_item    color    qty
1     123          1           red      5   
2     123          1           green    2
```

what i want to achieve is to update table item become like this :

```
id_item       color           stock
1         red,green,yellow   5,18,30
```

what i do is :

```
$query = mysql_query("select a.color as color, a.stock as stock, b.id_item as id_item,b.color as colors,b.qty as qty from item as a, cart as b where a.id_item = b.id_item and b.id_trans = '123' ");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$colors = $result['colors'];
$color = explode(",",$result['color']);
$stock = explode(",",$result['stock']);
$flag = array_search($colors,$color);
$stock[$flag] = $stock[$flag] - $result['qty'];
$stock = implode(',',$stock);

mysql_query("update item set stock = '$stock' where id_item = '$result[id_item]'");
```

}

from a code that i write above, i have some problem.
My problem is, the result its like this : 5,20,30 & 10,18,30. So, when i update to the table item, it just change like this :

```
id_item       color           stock
1         red,green,yellow   10,18,30
```

What i want to achieve is to implode that stock become 5,18,30.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve that or can anyone tell me there is a wrong in my code?
thx

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Any possibility that you could fix the data struture so you have the list stored in a table rather than as a string?  Your data structure is making very poor use of the relational database, which in turn makes this problem difficult to solve.

Comment: Yes, i think so, it would be easy if i make an own field for a different color. I just figure out, can i make it happen or not, if can't maybe i will change a table structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its clearer than your previous attempt ;)
Try this and see if it works:

```
unset($color);unset($stock);
$query = mysql_query("select a.color as color, a.stock as stock, b.id_item as id_item,b.color as colors,b.qty as qty from item as a, cart as b where a.id_item = b.id_item and b.id_trans = '123' ");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $colors = $result['colors'];
    $id = $result[id_item];
    if(!isset($color))
    {
        $color = explode(",",$result['color']);
    }
    if(!isset($stock))
    {
    $stock = explode(",",$result['stock']);
    }

    $flag = array_search($colors,$color);
    $stock[$flag] = $stock[$flag] - $result['qty'];
}

$stock = implode(',',$stock);
mysql_query("update item set stock = '".$stock."' where id_item = ".$id);
```

I'll be honest though, the way you use the database is terrible. That is not how databases should be used.

Comment: it's working, thx. First, i know that structure it's terrible and i know it would make a complicated in future, but i must do that for some reason. I now that maybe it would be the best way if i make a their own field. Anyway, thx for your answer and suggestion..;)